# SQLite Prefix search JAVA Virtual Table

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, match

I have a virtual table in SQLite on my android application. I am running the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM virtualTable WHERE desc MATCH '75*'
```

this basically equates to, but is faster then:

```
SELECT * FROM virtualTable WHERE desc like '75%'
```

Is there any equivalent MATCH query that i could get the results similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM virtualTable WHERE desc like '%75'
```

Module I am using is FTS3

Comment: `WHERE desc MATCH '*75'`?

Comment: @GMB that doesn't work surprisingly